# How to get latitude and longitude using Here Map for android SDK?

Tags: android, geolocation, here-api

I wanted to add the marker on touched location on Here Map. Also, i wanted to show the latitude and longitude where i touched the location.
I am successful in showing the marker But i cannot able to show the latitude and longitude in toast message.

I have implemented my own gesture listener as explained in the doc:
    `public class MyOnGestureListener implements MapGesture.OnGestureListener`
In this there is an overridden method i used:

```
@Override
public boolean onTapEvent(PointF p) {
    // Toast.makeText(context, " Show latitude and langitude on touched location: " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    return true;
}
```

In this i wanted to show latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Map#pixelToGeo(PointF point)` API to get the `GeoCoordinate` from the `PointF`. Then you can obtain the latitude and longitude values from the `GeoCoordinate`.

[Map pixelToGeo API Reference](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-map.html#topic-apiref__pixeltogeo-pointf)

Answer (score 0):

@AndrewJC is right. But for beginner, I will explain a bit.
Here SDK has following implementation in their basic positioning section

`PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener`

which provides an interface, `onPositionUpdated`. From this you can get `GeoPosition` . Use this `GeoPosition` to get latitude and longitude.

```
double latitude = geoposition.getCoordinate().getLatitude();
double longitude = geoposition.getCoordinate().getLongitude();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
With pixelToGeo(android.graphics.PointF point)
Geocoordinate geototap = map.pixelToGeo(pointf);
Double lat = geototap.getLatitude();
Double lng = geototap.getLongitude();
```